# networkmanager in kubuntu does not show DSL connection !

Tags: network-manager, kde, dsl

I have a dial-up connection for the internet which works perfectly well in GNOME using DSL settings in which i provide username, password, ip, gateway, netmask etc.

But in KDE i cannot do anything. After having provided the necessary information 
i don't see any available connection of DSL in the system tray. I have provided tow screenshot to show what is happening.
[image]

the wired connection is shown. But for DSL there is no such thing that i could click on to start using the web.
[image]

you can see that there is a connection under the DSL tab but it is not available at the 
tray.

is it this bug:[Bug #447241](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-widget-networkmanagement/+bug/447241)  ??

It was reported in 2009. Now it is 2011. After several releases of kubuntu the bug should be fixed by now.

my question is how can i bring the DSL connection in the tray and solve the issue ?

/*Please don't suggest to install other network management tool because to solve the issue of internet connection, i need an internet connection to install other package rendering me in a recursive loop.
And please don't suggest `pppoeconf` . It makes the wired connection unavailabe. If CLI works then why this GUI.*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a workaround, uninstall plasma-networkmanagement (I don't know if that is its exact name) and type in "autostart" in the KDE menu. once open, add a new startup item, with the command "nm-applet". Then log out and back in again. This will give you the GNOME NetworkManager. Rough, I know but it works. For some reason the KDE version seems to lag badly behind it's GNOME counterpart.

I assume you still have GNOME on there?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this means KDE takes a lot, a lot of time to fix the obvious bugs. Why don't kubuntu provide alternative application which is less problematic like WICD. I hope the applications in KDE will be as up to dated as its GNOME counterpart in near future. I always wish them the best. :)

Comment: It's not KDE's problem per se - they don't make either NetworkManager or the KDE GUIs to it. That's down to the team that makes NetworkManager (aka Red Hat).

It wouldn't be a bad idea to have GNOME's version of the GUI in there; in the latest releases of Kubuntu it looks just like a QT program

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in networkmanagement with commit:

```
commit 68ebd8231f942154cd743d4007b8ab9e8689808b
Author: Lamarque V. Souza <lamarque@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 12 21:52:11 2011 -0300

    Allow DSL connections be associated to ethernet interfaces.

    CCBUG: 204170
```

Upstream bug:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204170

You just need to update networkmanagement plasmoid.